# release text from label

Tags: iphone

Hii...

I am making an iphone application in which I have generated the buttons programmatically using loop concept. But whenever put I put the value for buttons then it get fix we cant change the number of buttons. I want to change the number of buttons how can I do this . Anyone has solution for it.
Please help me.

Thanks alot.

Code is:

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    int z = [txtfrequency.text  intValue];

    NSLog(@"Value of z is :%d",z);
    //int x = 20;
    int y = 250;
    //create a new dynamic button
    for (int j=0; j<z; j++)
    {

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, y , 50, 30);

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        //[button setTitle:@"Button x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTag:j];

        button.frame = frame;

        CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(100, y , 50, 30);
        /*UITextField *label = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame1];
        //[button setTitle:@"Button x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [label setTag:j];
        label.frame = frame1;*/



        UITextField * textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
        textFieldRounded.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //text color
        textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];  //font size
        textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //background color
        textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   // no auto correction support

        textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // type of the keyboard
        textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // type of the return key

        textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right



        textFieldRounded.delegate = self;
        [textFieldRounded setTag:j];


        [button reloadInputViews];
        [textFieldRounded removeFromSuperview];

        [scroll addSubview:button];
        [scroll addSubview:textFieldRounded];
        y= y+50;


    } 
}
```

Comment: can u make the question more clear?? how you want the buttons to be created?

Comment: int z = [txtfrequency.text  intValue];

Comment: int z = [txtfrequency.text  intValue];
I am getting the value of button by using above line code. Let first time I put the value of z= 5, and i get 5 buttons but if we want to change the number of buttons or want to decrease the buttons...I am not able to do this.

Comment: I am not clear what exactly you want... Try removing all the buttons and create them again.

Comment: How is the question related to the title?????

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the existing buttons before you add new ones or you will end up piling them up. Eventually it will eat up the memory. Instead of assigning the same tag to both button and the text field, you can assign a container view with the same tag. Later, you can remove the subview saying `[[scroll viewWithTag:j] removeFromSuperview];`.

Since, they seem to be rows, you can also simplify this by looking at `UITableView` with each row containing a button and text field. For a table view, changing the number of rows (which is what you want I guess) will be as simple as changing the number returned by the data source.